# Python says "No Module named SALib" despite successful install in cmd

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to perform a sensitivity analysis using the SALib module in Python(Spyder) and I installed it using "pip install SALib" in cmd prompt. The install was performed successfully however python says "No module named SALib" when I run the command "import SALib".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: run ``pip freeze`` & check if module exists.

Comment: Have you performed the tests/prereqs in the docs: https://salib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html?

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I figured out my error. I was installing it in cmd when I was supposed to install in Conda Prompt since I use Anaconda for my coding